# Adding new values to a filtered pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am using Python to make a visualization generator for prime factors, but I'm having trouble linking the colors with the unique prime factors of a given number. Here's the basic set up (I'm using pyprimes to get factors for the data variable, but this hard-coded list works for this):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [2,2,2,3,7,7,23]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["prime"])
colors = [
'DarkOrange',
'DeepSkyBlue',
'Yellow',
'Purple',
'Salmon',
'Lime',
'Peru',
'LightPink'
]
```

All that is good, now I want to link some unique colors to the unique primes in the DataFrame. One way is to do:

```
for unique_prime in set(data):
        df['color']= np.where(df['prime'] == unique_prime,colors.pop(),#what to put here?)
```

But of course, whatever I put in the last slot ends up replacing all the previous color values at the end of the for loop. Is there something I can put in the last spot that says to ignore the other values? Or is there a better way to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: lots of people ask crap questions, I wouldnt consider this to be one... that said I wouldnt put a disclaimer at the top ... if its crap the community will let you know, but being your first question does not protect it from being closed if its crap.  and the disclaimer probably will cause lots of people to just skip over your answer(or worse vote to close without even reading it)

Comment: not a crap question ;) but I'm struggling to grok what you're trying to do in your loop. What's your desired output? Thanks for giving example input, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Aside: it's usually a good idea to give a concrete example of the output you want.  This helps avoid ambiguity about what you're after.]

IIUC, you can build a number-to-colour dictionary and then use the `replace` method. For example:

```
>>> cmap = dict(zip(df.prime.unique(), colors))
>>> cmap
{23: 'Purple', 2: 'DarkOrange', 3: 'DeepSkyBlue', 7: 'Yellow'}
>>> df["color"] = df["prime"].replace(cmap)
>>> df
   prime        color
0      2   DarkOrange
1      2   DarkOrange
2      2   DarkOrange
3      3  DeepSkyBlue
4      7       Yellow
5      7       Yellow
6     23       Purple
```

Answer (score 1):

An all Pandas solution would be to make the color map a pandas dataframe and then join it to the primes dataframe:

```
cmap = pd.DataFrame({'prime' : [2,3,7,23], 
                     'color' : ['DarkOrange','DeepSkyBlue','Yellow','Purple']})
print df.merge(cmap)
   prime        color
0      2   DarkOrange
1      2   DarkOrange
2      2   DarkOrange
3      3  DeepSkyBlue
4      7       Yellow
5      7       Yellow
6     23       Purple
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you wish to iterate over `data` and assign each value its own color.

In that case I'd do:

```
counter = 0
for unique_prime in set(data):
    df['color']= np.where(df['prime'] == unique_prime, colors[counter])
    counter += 1
```

and then make sure you're not running out of predefined colors. You can write this in a shorter way by doing:

```
for counter, unique_prime in enumerate(set(data)):
    df['color']= np.where(df['prime'] == unique_prime, colors[counter])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
mask = df["prime"] == unique_prime
df[mask]["color"] = colors.pop()
```

although I could be wrong I havent used pandas much